# Bot responding on mention and also when anyone reply bot message

Tags: python, discord.py

I wrote this code for bot response when someone mentions the bot. But the problem is when anyone replies bot message, it also responds and I don't want this type of response! Now what to do to solve this issue?

**Code:**

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
    if message.author.bot:
        return
    if f"<@!{self.bot.user.id}>" or f"<@?{self.bot.user.id}>" in message.content.split():
        pfx = get_prefix(self.bot, message)
        await message.channel.send(f"My prefix : {pfx}")
```

**Bot response:**

That's ok!

[OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6f63.png)

Don't want this type of response!

[Problm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcAwm.png)

Please help to fix this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check if the messages references another message (i.e. a reply).

```
if message.reference is None and (f"<@!{self.bot.user.id}>" or f"<@?{self.bot.user.id}>" in message.content.split()):
    pfx = get_prefix(self.bot, message)
    await message.channel.send(f"My prefix : {pfx}")
```

Note that this will stop responding to any type of message than contains a reference: replies, pins, and cross-reference messages.